# Permissioned ledger records by organization in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have five organizations in my fabric network: R1, R2, R3, R4 and AdminORG. Every organization has one peer and all five of them have installed smart contract S1, are connected to the same channel C1, have visibility over the same ledger L1 and there's only one Orderer O1.

The assets for the world state are defined as:
Location: (owner[organization], id, address)
Product: (owner[organization], id, name)

The ledger L1 keeps record of transactions called Stock Movement(source [location], destination[location], product, quantity) between all organizations in the network.

Since all organization peers are connected to the same channel they can see all the transactions in ledger L1.

Is it possible to establish a policy or some kind of resource control such that for example: organization R1 copy of ledger L1 only has a copy of those assets and transactions where R1 is the owner of the location (source or destination) involved in the stock movement? That way organizations will only be able to see stock movements where they are a participant.

I also would like to keep organization AdminORG visibility over all transactions in ledger L1.

Previously I was able to achieve this using Hyperledger Composer ACL's but since it's reaching its EOL I'm not using it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I read over your nicely written explanation and instantly thought of private data collections.

Private data collections let you store and access data only from peers who are part of the collection. For your example it means you create collections for orgs who should interact with each other for every stock. So let R1 and R2 create a collection and the other ones are not able to see/access the data.

Your AdminORG can be part of every collection. So it sees the data being transmitted via those collections.

Hopefully this meets your requirements. You can read [this overview explanation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html) and this [example/tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html) to see whether this approach meets your requirements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried using private data collections but it doesn't fit my use case since I would need to create a collection for each organization combination: CollectionAB, CollectionAC, CollectionBC and so on...It won't scale well.

Is there a way to only distribute a transaction to a set of specific members/peers in a channel?.

According to a fabric video it should be possible to do it but I wasn't able to find anything about this on the docs: https://youtu.be/js3Zjxbo8TM?t=55 

Thanks!

Comment: Ah ok. When you found a solution for this it would be cool if you could come back and share your approach here!